# Leaflet map scrolls uncontrollably

Tags: leaflet, proj

I'm fairly new to Leaflet, but a veteran web map programmer.

I'm just now building a map utility for an embedded system (Qlikview), and it seems to work nicely enough.

But there's one fairly serious issue, which I can't get a handle on.

The map utilizes an open map tile service as background basemap, that only serves tiles in UTM zone 32. Hence my Leaflet map is created in UTM zone 32 by utilizing Proj4 functionality. The problem is, that my necessary coverage area extends well into areas normally covered by UTM zone 33.

Whenever I zoom into an area belonging to UTM zone 33, the map starts scrolling downwards without any apparent cause. And it keeps scrolling, and there seems to be nothing I can do to stop it.

Furthermore, panning and zooming is severely inhibited in this area. I've tried to increase the map maxBounds a lot into zone 33, but it doesn't change anything.

There are no such problems whatsoever when working in the normal zone 32 coverage area.

Can anybody help me in how to get this unwanted scrolling to stop ? Or at least give me an idea as to where I should start looking for a solution ?

Regards,
Lars I Nielsen

Comment: Could you please provide the tileservice you're using so we can try and reproduce your problem? It would be even better if you also supplied the relevant code you're using.

Comment: Well, as I wrote, it's embedded within a desktop program UI. And although the core is Javascript, there are important differencies.

But I'm currently building it as a standalone HTML, but sofar it hasn't shown the problem experienced in Qlikview :-S